# 3D / 4D Matrix manipulation

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization

I often struggle with slow Matlab processing due to high numbers of for loops.
Maybe you can help me with this example, which would help me in other cases as well: Is it possible to completely transfer it to matrices?

```
R = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
u1 = 200; u2 = 300; v1 = 100; v2 = 222; w1 = 123; w2 = 312;
px = 20; py = 30; pz = 25;
a = 20; b = 30; c = 25;
Ellipse = zeros(500,600,500)

for i=u1:u2
    for j=v1:v2
        for k=w1:w2
            x=[i-px;j-py;k-pz];
            x=R*x;
            if (x(1)/a)^2+(x(2)/b)^2+(x(3)/c)^2<1                      
                Ellipse(i,j,k)=1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: A smaller working example with output would be useful...

Comment: Also, is `x` always going to be the same three numbers? It will for your current `R`...

Comment: @Dan I agree, a smaller working example would do, I just copied from the existing file. Sorry for that. I am not sure, but x should be calculated in each loop. Therefore, it will always change.

Comment: @IKavanagh Surely, there is a `;` at the end of each line. It was lost when I copied from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach that runs about 2 orders of magnitude faster

```
R = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
u1 = 200; u2 = 300; v1 = 100; v2 = 222; w1 = 123; w2 = 312;
px = 20; py = 30; pz = 25;
a = 20; b = 30; c = 25;
Ellipse = zeros(500,600,500);

% Create mesh of points to process
vx = (u1:u2) - px;
vy = (v1:v2) - py;
vz = (w1:w2) - pz;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(vx, vy, vz);

% Compute R*x
V = [X(:)'; Y(:)'; Z(:)'];
V = R * V;

% Divide by ellipse axes
M = diag([1/a, 1/b, 1/c]);
V = M * V;

% Determine if norm criteria is met
index = norm(V') < 1;
Ellipse(X(index), Y(index), Z(index)) = 1;
```

Agree with @Dan, a smaller working example would make it easier to test.

Comment: Thanks @dpmcmlxxvi for giving me the right idea. Totally forgot about `meshgrid`.
I changed a couple of things as `% Determine if norm criteria is met
index = norm(V') < 1;
Ellipse(X(index), Y(index), Z(index)) = 1;` did not work for me. See the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing more than simple mathematical operations matrices can be tricky.
Here you can (should) reduce the size of Ellipse because you are not using most of its entries.
All you need is (101,123,190) and things will be much faster, especially the way you are accessing the matrix entries, remember MATLAB will eventually store the matrix as just an array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have to mention that I need this size of (500,600,500). It is part of a further processing in the code.

Answer (score 0):

@dpmcmlxxvi Thank you very much for the answer. At first, sorry for the large example. I used your answer with some modification as `norm(XY)` did not work for me.(smaller example and valueas adapted to run properly)

```
R = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
u1 = 50; u2 = 90; v1 = 20; v2 = 50; w1 = 30; w2 = 60;
px = 60; py = 25; pz = 50;
a = 10; b = 20; c = 15;
Ellipse = zeros(100,200,100);

% Create mesh of points to process
vx = (u1:u2) - px;
vy = (v1:v2) - py;
vz = (w1:w2) - pz;
[X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(vx, vy, vz);

% Compute R*x
V = [X(:)'; Y(:)'; Z(:)'];
V = R * V;

% Divide by ellipse axes
M = diag([1/a, 1/b, 1/c]);
V = M * V;

% Apply criteria
Vsq = V.*V;
crit = Vsq(1,:)+Vsq(2,:)+Vsq(3,:);

% Look for indices in the meshgrid fullfilling criteria
xe = X(find(crit<1));
ye = Y(find(crit<1));
ze = Z(find(crit<1));

xi = ceil(abs(xe+px));
yi = ceil(abs(ye+py));
zi = ceil(abs(ze+pz));

% Set values at correpsonding indices to 1
linind = sub2ind(size(Ellipse),xi,yi,zi);

Ellipse(linind) = 1;
```

It works fine and all for loops have been removed.